# What would happen if the gravitational force was repulsive?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

Since my young age, I have always been somewhat afraid of looking up at the sky for one weird reason. It always made me think about this irrational deep dark fear that I have:

- What if we stopped being attracted to the earth, and fell through the sky then into space ?

After a while, it also made me wonder if this could actually happen. I surely don't know gravitation in details, but let's stick to Newton's theory for the moment.

We know this :

$$F = G \frac{m_1 m_2}{r^2}\ $$

But instead of being an attractive force between the two objects, let's say this is repulsive.

- What would happen then ?
- I am almost convinced that it would not change much at the atomic scale, since gravitation is mostly negligeable for this order of magnitude. Is this actually the case ?

On the other hand, I would expect dramatic changes for planets (do they explode ?) and more generally in astronomy.

Obviously, if anything other than free falling into outer space would happen to us, I would very much like to know about it.

Also, if anyone could come up with a possible extrapolation considering **more advanced** gravitation I would be very interested, but I may be asking too much.

Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: And what exactly is wrong with this question ?
I believe this is entirely okay in this context :"Some subjective questions are allowed, but “subjective” does not mean “anything goes”. All subjective questions are expected to be constructive."

I am providing a frame of work along with some hypothesis. It really seems like an interesting question to me, nothing off-topic.

Comment: What's wrong with your question is that it's overly broad (there is *way* too much to cover here) so there isn't a specific answer to a specific question. If you want "what if's" answered, you could try [worldbuilding.se], though I doubt this is on topic there either.

Comment: It's off topic, I believe, because it is not about the physics of our universe.

Answer (score 1):

> What would happen then ?

You and earth would behave as if you are two like charges. A whole lot have been written on this under the banner **electrodynamics**, its practically impossible to analyze every phenomenon in this short space, but people have analyzed them in many textbooks on the said topic. I am sure you are motivated enough to study them.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If gravity was repulsive instead of attractive, the large clouds of gas in the early universe would have stayed clouds of gas, rather than collapsing into stars.  With no stars, there is no nuclear fusion, which means that everything in the universe stays in its original state, rather than being fused into the "heavier" elements that make up you and me.  This means that you and I never would have had the chance to communicate in Physics SE because neither one of us would exist.